# Use regex for extracting month in a column - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following dataframe:

```
                  Data
0           12/25/2020
1           10/25/2020
2  2020-09-12 00:00:00
3  2020-12-09 00:00:00
```

I'm using the following (python) code to extract the first two potential numbers to represent a month:

```
df['Data'].apply(lambda x: re.match('.*([1-2][0-9]{3})', x).group(1))
```

However, it returns a NaN dataframe. When i test it in regex101, it works (link: https://regex101.com/r/QpacQ0/1). So, i have two questions:

- Is there a better way to work with dates from an user input? I mean, i'm building a script to recognize by position and then convert to a datetime object.
- And second, why can't this code recognize the months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```py
df['Month'] = df['Data'].str.extract(r'\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\b')
```

When using `re.match('.*([1-2][0-9]{3})', x)`, you actually match any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, from the start of string (since `re.match` only searches for a match at the start of string) and then capture `1` or `2` digit and then any three digits. So, you actually match the *last occurrence* of a specific 4-digit sequence, not a month-like number.

With `.str.extract(r'\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\b')`, you extract the first occurrence of `0` followed with a non-zero digit, or `1` followed with `0`, `1` or `2`, as whole word, due to `\b` word boundaries.

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y493GV/1).

If the `Data` is not a string column, convert it into one:

```py
df['Month'] = df['Data'].astype(str).str.extract(r'\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\b')
#                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, man! Do you know if is there a way to get the position?

Comment: I was trying to type: 

df['Data'].apply(lambda x: re.match('\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\b', x)).

 However, it keeps returning None. Do you know why?

Comment: @bellotto I suggest something like `df['Data'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\b', x).start() if re.search(r'\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\b', x) else -1)`, or use a function where you would run `re.search` only once.